# How to do SQL query with string parameter value in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to get a string value from parameter and get all names of the companies(YRITYS) where name starts with letter from parameter but I am getting nothing in return. What is the correct syntax to do this?

```
public IEnumerable<Asiakas> GetByName(string arvo)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT ASNRO, YRITYS, SUKUNIMI, ETUNIMI, LAHIOSOITE, POSTITP, POSTINRO " +
                         "FROM dbo.ASIAKAS " +
                         "WHERE YRITYS LIKE '@KIRJAIN' " +
                         "ORDER BY ASNRO";
            using (var cmd = Context.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@KIRJAIN", arvo));
                var tulos = ToList(cmd);
                return tulos;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `new SqlParameter("KIRJAIN", arvo)`

Comment: Don't quote when you use parameter the library will add the right quoting if needed -- just `... LIKE @KIRJAIN ...` **not** `... LIKE '@KIRJAIN' ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use quotes in the sql, and don't use @ in the parameter

```
public IEnumerable<Asiakas> GetByName(string arvo)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT ASNRO, YRITYS, SUKUNIMI, ETUNIMI, LAHIOSOITE, POSTITP, POSTINRO " +
                         "FROM dbo.ASIAKAS " +
                         "WHERE YRITYS LIKE @KIRJAIN " +
                         "ORDER BY ASNRO";
            using (var cmd = Context.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("KIRJAIN", arvo));
                var tulos = ToList(cmd);
                return tulos;
            }
        }
```

Comment: But if i try it like that and do "YRITYS LIKE @KIRJAIN%" it just returns error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Also `cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("KIRJAIN", arvo))` is generally preferred to `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("KIRJAIN", arvo))`.

Comment: @Steffe30  that's different than your question..... if you want the %   in the parameter do ```cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("KIRJAIN", arvo+"%"));```

Comment: or if you want to do it in the sql ```"WHERE YRITYS LIKE @KIRJAIN + '%' " +```

Comment: as a further note, parameters are not text replacements, they are tsql variables